# How to know battery technology Li-Ion or other?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a program that will get the battery information and also type of the battery. I just got battery information, but don't know how to get type and all like is it Li-ion battery or other.
Please suggest me how to get that info?

Answer (score 0):

Register to the broadcast ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED and you can get it from the extras EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY.

Eg:

```
final Intent intent = mContext.registerReceiver(null,
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
final Bundle extras = intent != null ? intent.getExtras() : null;
String batteryType = extras != null ? extras.getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY) : null;
```